# C# Regex expression matching multiple groups

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have some text in the

tags such like

```
<p>This is text a</p><p>This is text ended without p</a>
```

I want to use Regex to match both classes and extract InnerText:

```
const string patternDesp = @"<p>(.+?)(</p>|</a>)";
```

But when I look at the `m.Groups[1]`, it only returns 1 match. `m.Groups[2]` gives me

```
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, it seems that I need to use `MatchCollection` instead of `Match`.